# Mongo DB querying from two different Schema(Services)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two Schemas running in my localhost via Node.Js. Let say the two services are Employee and Employee Salary.

```
  localhost/emp
  var EmpSchema = mongoose.Schema({

     Emp_ID : Number,
     Emp_Email_ID : String,
     Emp_First_Name : String,
     Emp_Last_Name : String,

   });

   localhost/empsalary

      var EmpSalarySchema = mongoose.Schema({

      Emp_ID : Number,
      Emp_Monthly_Salary : Number,
      Emp_Annual_Salary : Number
     Emp_Loan_Detail : String,

     });
```

How do I need to query in **get method** such that I get Emp_Monthly_Salary and Emp_First_Name

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: I'm very new to mongo DB and non relational data bases.. So giving out tries

Answer (score 3):

MongoDb is a NoSQL Database and one of its limitations is that it not allows making JOINs between collections directly in one query.

The typical ways to get around this limitiation:

- query one collection and use the mongoose "populate" feature to add data from other collections to the result set: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html (probably the preferred solution for your issue)
- remodel your data so it fits better to the typical queries you have (and often: allow some redundancy), so if you always query firstname and salary together you might want to store them together using a subdocument: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html
- just use two queries and do the JOINing manually in node.js code
- if your data and your queries are really requiring lots of JOINs (are very relational), mongo might not be the right choice for your problem (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/)

Comment: please consider accepting an answer if it is correct and helps, otherwise please comment what you are missing, so we can help